# How to take the date from the name?

Tags: bash

I need to delete files using a bash script if they are older than two weeks. Here is an example file name bliznetsy_17-07-2023__03-01.dump. The file creation date is sewn into the name (in this case, the creation date is 07/17/2023). How can I get the creation date of the file from the name, so that the script would correctly perceive this date?

The folder with the files is on the Linux virtual machine.

I tried like this, but it crashes with an error that the date is incorrect

```
#!/bin/bash

backup_folder="/dev/backupsTest"  


current_date=$(date +%s)
two_weeks_ago=$(date -d "2 weeks ago" +%s)


for file in "$backup_folder"/*; do

  filename=$(basename "$file")
  date_part=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d'_' -f2)
  file_date=$(date -d "${date_part//__/ }" +%s)

  if [[ $file_date -lt $two_weeks_ago ]] && ! [[ "${date_part:0:2}" =~ ^(05|15|25)$ ]]; then
    # Удаляем файл
    rm "$file"
    echo "Удален файл: $file"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Try this yourself: `filename='bliznetsy_17-07-2023__03-01.dump'; [[ $filename =~ (.*)_([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{4})_(.*) ]] && declare -p BASH_REMATCH`

Comment: please update the question with the complete error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing OP's current error message ...

Assuming the mentioned error message has to do with the `date -d` call, eg:

```
$ file=/some/parent/dir/bliznetsy_17-07-2023__03-01.dump

$ filename=$(basename "$file")
$ date_part=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d'_' -f2)
$ file_date=$(date -d "${date_part//__/ }" +%s)
date: invalid date ‘17-07-2023’
```

The issue is that `date_part` is not in a format that `date -d` understands, ie:

```
$ typeset -p date_part
declare -- date_part="17-07-2023"

$ date -d "17-07-2023" +%s
date: invalid date ‘17-07-2023’
```

One quick-n-easy fix is to break `date_part` into components and put back together in a format that `date -d` understands, eg:

```
$ IFS='-' read -r d m y <<< "$date_part"
$ typeset -p d m y
declare -- d="17"
declare -- m="07"
declare -- y="2023"

$ date -d "$y-$m-$d" +%s
1689570000
```

Rolling this back into OP's current code:

```
# replace this:

filename=$(basename "$file")
date_part=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d'_' -f2)
file_date=$(date -d "${date_part//__/ }" +%s)

# with this:

filename=$(basename "$file")
date_part=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d'_' -f2)
IFS='-' read -r d m y <<< "$date_part"
file_date=$(date -d "$y-$m-$d" +%s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Bash provides `[[ $var =~ ERE ]]` where the *Extended Regular Expression* (ERE) can provide parentheticals `(..)` to capture matched portions of `$var`. The full ERE match is stored in `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` and the matched portions within parenthesis are stored in `${BASH_REMATCH[n]}` where `n` is the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.. grouping matched.

In your case you can simply do:

```bash
filename="${file##*/}"                      # use parameter expansion
[[ $filename =~ ^[^0-9]+([0-9-]+).*$ ]]     # fill BASH_REMATCH array

# use BASH_REMATCH result with parameter expansion for indexing to form date
fdate="${BASH_REMATCH[1]:3:2}/${BASH_REMATCH[1]:0:2}/${BASH_REMATCH[1]:6:4}"
```

`fdate` will hold the file date in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`.

You can make things more readable by assigning `"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` to a shorter variable name and then use the shorter variable in the rearrangement of the date values, e.g.

```bash
# use BASH_REMATCH result with parameter expansion for indexing to form date
d="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fdate="${d:3:2}/${d:0:2}/${d:6:4}"
```

(entirely up to you)

**Example Use/Output**

Adding your sample `file` and an `echo` for output you would have:

```
$ (
> file="some/path/to/bliznetsy_17-07-2023__03-01.dump"
>
> filename="${file##*/}"                      # use parameter expansion
> [[ $filename =~ ^[^0-9]+([0-9-]+).*$ ]]     # fill BASH_REMATCH array
>
> # use BASH_REMATCH result with parameter expansion for indexing to form date
> fdate="${BASH_REMATCH[1]:3:2}/${BASH_REMATCH[1]:0:2}/${BASH_REMATCH[1]:6:4}"
>
> echo "$fdate"
> )
07/17/2023
```

Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to compare dates is to format those in a numerically comparable format of `YYYYmmdd`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

backup_folder='./bkp'

# Collect reference date in a numerically comparable form YYYYmmdd
two_weeks_ago=$(date '+%Y%m%d' -d '2 weeks ago')

for file in "$backup_folder/"*; do
  # Regex capture date elements from file name
  if [[ $file =~ .*/?_([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})__.*\.dump ]]; then
    # Assembles Regex-captured date elements in the same
    # numerically comparable date format as reference date
    dump_date="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    # Numerically compare file date with reference date
    if [[ $dump_date -lt $two_weeks_ago ]]; then
      # rm -- "$file"
      printf 'Удален файл: %s\n' "$file"
    fi
  fi
done
```

Bash could also work with actual file creation dates if those were relevant:

Use Bash's built-in file creation date comparison operators `-ot` `-nt`.

See `help test`:

> FILE1 -nt FILE2  True if file1 is newer than file2 (according to
> modification date).
>
> FILE1 -ot FILE2  True if file1 is older than file2.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

backup_folder='/dev/backupsTest'

# Use a variable to store the name of a reference file
ref_file=''

# Prepare to delete the ref file on script end
trap 'rm -f "$ref_file"' EXIT INT

# Create the reference file or exit if failed
ref_file="$(mktemp)" || exit 1

# Set the creation date of the reference file to 2 weeks ago
touch -d "2 weeks ago" "$ref_file"

for file in "$backup_folder/"*; do
  # If file older than reference file
  if [[ "$file" -ot "$ref_file" ]]; then
    echo rm -- "$file"
    printf 'Удален файл: %s\n' "$file"
  fi
done
```

Alternatively use `find` to delete your backup files older than 2 weeks ago:

```bash
backup_folder='/dev/backupsTest'
refFile=$(mktemp) &&
touch -d '2 weeks ago' "$refFile" &&
find "$backup_folder" \
  -maxdepth 1 \
  -type f -not -newer "$refFile" \
  -exec rm -f -- {} \+ &&
rm -f "$refFile"
```

Answer (score 0):

What's missing is the swap of month and day. Try:

```
date -d "${date_part:3:2}/${date_part:0:2}/${date_part:6}" +%s
```

In bash `${var:offset:length}` expands as `length` characters of the value of `var`, starting at character `offset` where the first character (leftmost) has offset 0.

Note: `${date_part//__/ }` seams useless, `cut` already took care of the underscores.